# Problems with Eclipse swing libraries

Tags: java

I am new to Java programming.I am running on Eclipse right now and it doesn't import Swing libraries.It shows a red X and it says Access restriction.Can anyone help me?

Comment: could you include the code? Maybe the problem is lying somewhere different. But it might be connected with [this](http://www.digizol.com/2008/09/eclipse-access-restriction-on-library.html)

Comment: please share the exact error message.

Answer (score 1):

As you said i am new so i am writing detailed steps for you to fix this issue. I am assuming your installation and class path settings are fine.

1) Right click on your project and click "**Properties**"

2) From left column select "**Java Build Path**"

3) Now select third tab "**Libraries**"

4) Click on "**JRE System Library**"

5) Now Remove selected **JRE System Library** via "**Remove**" button.

6) Now in order to Add it back, Select "**Add Library**" and select the JRE System Library

Its default library It should work for your if installation and class path settings are fine.

Comment: Thankyou very much..it worked

Comment: sounds good :) @nana

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you are saying and like to ask you if:

- you got the newest (proper) JDK (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html the left link)
- you got a good JRE (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre7-downloads-1880261.html)
- you should also check your windows permissions set yourself as admin
- also if all else fails i'd try netbeans since this is like a really universal IDE, you can download newest netbeans + jdk on site above aswell (right link)

hope i could be off service 
And welcome to the wonderfull world of Java